# Loading json from an external domain

Tags: jsonp

I've been trying all day how to load a json object cross domain. I was using a json to jsonp service at jsonp.nodejitsu.com but that has been down all day and I need to do this on my own.

This is where I've got so far:

```
$.getJSON("https://cex.io/api/ticker/WDC/BTC/?callback=?",function(data){console.log(data);});
```

Can anybody explain to me why this is not working? I am becoming very frustrated. I thought this was supposed to be easy!

Comment: It will only work if the site implements JSONP. If you were using a conversion service, isn't it because the target site doesn't support JSONP by itself?

Comment: Yes I was just under the assumption that json to jsonp was now possible via jquery based on some search results. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: It comes close, when i have  ?callback=?  it seems to bypass cross origin bottlenecks. The object I want is returned, I see it the network values in Firebug, the only thing is the success function is never called. I'm so close and so far.

Comment: It doesn't call the success function because the response isn't valid JSONP, so it's not successful.

Comment: Yeah, I guess really the only way is to write something in python and query my own server for the JSON.